# There are two points on the curve given by the equation$ x^2+y^2-xy+5y+2x = 8$

Tags: derivatives

There are two points on the curve given by the equation $x^2+y^2-xy+5y+2x = 8$
at which the tangent to the curve is at an angle of $\pi/4$ to the x-axis. Find the equation of the straight line joining these two points.

Comment: I suggest you take a [tour](http://math.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+y^2-xy+5y+2x=8$

Differentiate with respect to x.

$2x+2yy'-y-xy'+5y'+2=0$

$y'(2y-x+5)+2x-y+2=0$

$y'=\frac{y-2x-2}{2y-x+5}$

This is the slope of the tangent line. We know that $\tan\alpha=a$ where $a$ is the slope of the line. (Do you want this proved?)

Thus

$\frac{y-2x-2}{2y-x+5}=\tan\frac{\pi}{4}=1$

$y-2x-2=2y-x+5$

$y=-x-7$

Done.